# JMeter - Generating a Summary Report

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I've implemented a BeanShell listener in my Jmeter test plan which I use to run a script that sends information after each request into Splunk. However, I'd now like to be able to generate a similar message at the end of each Thread run, regardless of whether or not there was an error in its execution.

At present when an error occurs I start the next thread. I'd like at this stage to be run another BeanShell script where I can collect and send summary inforation for that thread into Splunk before it starts the next Thread. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean at end of thread or end of thread group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option is to code a class implementing ThreadListener:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/ThreadListener.html

See also this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf